# How to implement skip() method in Swift InputStream

Tags: swift

I am trying to implement a method that can do the following to an InputStream:

```
 /**
* Skips n bytes of input.
* @param n the number of bytes to skip
* @return  the actual number of bytes skipped.
*/

func skip(n: Int) throws-> Int {
    let res = inputStream.skip(n) //Value of type 'InputStream' has no member 'skip'
    pos_ += res
    return res
}
```

How can I go about achieving this in Swift? Thanks.

Comment: You could read and discard the bytes...

Comment: I did as  advised and the following was my solution:
func skip(n: Int) throws-> Int {
        var res = 0
        while is_.hasBytesAvailable {
            let lenbytes_read = is_.read(buffer, maxLength: n)
            if lenbytes_read < 0 {
                throw is_.streamError!
            } else if lenbytes_read == 0 {
                break
            }
            res = lenbytes_read
            pos_ += lenbytes_read
            //discard the bytes without assigning into data object
            buffer.deallocate()
            is_.close()
        }
        return res
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Cristlik, I decided to add an extension to read and discard the bytes:

```
extension InputStream {
func skip(inputStream: InputStream, n: Int) throws-> Int {
    var remaining = n
    var nr = 0
    if n <= 0 {
        return 0
    }
    let maxSkipBufferSize = 2048
    let  size = min(maxSkipBufferSize, remaining)
    var skipBuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: size)
    while remaining > 0 {
        nr = inputStream.read(&skipBuffer, maxLength: min(size, remaining))
        if (nr < 0) {
            break
        }
        remaining -= nr
    }
    return n - remaining
}}
```